# Access a variable in a controller from another controller

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a way to access some variables which I assigned values in one controller(say: controller A) in another controller(say: controller B). One of the controllers contains my main project but the other is where I implemented 'Date Picker'. i want  to move the date from the Date Picker controller to my App controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot as the other controller does not/may not live during the execution of the correct controller. Even if it *was* possible logically one controller have nothing in common - IMHO breaking modularity of MVC pattern.

Refactor code to `lib/`, `ApplicationController` or some model (separate or divided as method) depending of application.

PS. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Data Picker" but it sounds like something that should be implemented in model(s).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've generated a model for it and it's working. I mean i can call the values from the other controller by finding all that has been saved.